What happens if everything something touches stops moving
In my story the most powerful type of weapon is a "stream sword" or a sword that makes whatever it touches stop moving for a limitless amount of time. So, for example, if the sword hits something, a person, then the person stops moving forever or if the sword hits a stream of water the water will stay there for the rest of time. This is all fine and good but if this sword touches any sort of field/wave they will stop moving which is a bit of a problem. So I was wondering about if the sword would even be useful for the user due to it stopping things like air?

The stream sword does not stop time it just stops movement
The sword does not stop the user of the sword/the sword itself.
The sword does stop everything it touches with the only exceptions being time, and space.


Do gravity/external forces affect things that have been stopped? If not, you would not be able to wield this sword because it is frozen behind a permanent layer of stopped air. If so, you would not be able to wield this sword because it is functionally equivalent to a regular sword.

Stop with respect to what frame of reference?  The Earth?  The Sun?  Centre of this galaxy?  Some other arbitrary point?  The whole point of relativity is that there is no "universal" frame of reference.

I would recommend: 1: it only works on what you want it to, so it isn't instantly encased in a monomolecular layer of nitrogen-oxygen ice that never moves forever and 2: by stop moving, we mean "cause to be in a permanent geosynchronous orbit at its current altitude".

...Or not, because at that point, it would take a few steps and a lot of space to work with, but I can give you time travel, which means we can skip all the steps and just bring the solutions from the future in which we've already brought all the solutions from the future, and the sword would be useful for instantly having already solved all problems before they ever happened.

This is g_s's -1th law of worldbuilding: if you have a tool that that lets you break the laws of physics, first see if you can turn it into a time machine.

Adding constraints that you have to be close to the surface of Earth and close to comoving with the surface of Earth would, I think, prevent it from being turned into a time machine.

Also... is this going to accumulate a layer of supercooled matter around the frozen matter around the sword?  Consider: gas molecule touches sword & stops (loses all kinetic energy, i.e. heat.  Another gas molecule collides with the stopped atom, which still does not move, and loses energy.  Sooner or later, this thing is going to start dripping liquid air...

so you have to carry the naked sword everywhere becasue you can't sheath it. It should also be rusty as shit since you can't clean it.

@gs I suspect a geostationary orbit wouldn't do what's wanted. (1) An orbit is around the centre of the earth, so if you're not already on the equator, you're crossing the equator twice every orbit; (2) any non-equatorial orbit will precess; (3) the Earth's land surface is subject to tides just like the sea, but it's more sense and so moves less (a bit over half a metre).

I’m voting to close this question because this question is about magic but is tagged [science-based] without explaining the magic in detail.

Is that better?

Why not give the sword the ability to undo its effects? Granted, that'd make it more of a 'magic wand' that "toggles" objects from static to dynamic and vice versa, but that is, in my opinion, more interesting than just forbidding any character from ever using it in the first place.

I'd rewrite some laws of physics to make this work. In your universe, there is a preferred frame of reference, and in this frame of reference the earth (or whatever landmass your characters are fighting on) is completely motionless and does not rotate. There's also a physical definition of "object" that excludes air, and the sword freezes one object at a time. You don't need to come up with this definition exactly, just deciding that it exists is probably enough.

Replace "stops" with "greatly slows down", and "forever" with "for a really long time".  Using absolutes will really trigger the physicists.

"if the sword hits a stream of water the water will stay there for the rest of time. This is all fine and good" so if I touch the sword at the Nile delta in Egypt, the river stops flowing all the way to Lake Victoria in the southern half of Africa? What happens to the water downstream of where I touch the river? If I touch the ocean, do all rivers on the planet stop flowing? What happens to the water that collects into the source of the river (e.g. rainfall)? What happens to ships in the river? Fish? Plants? Anyone jumping on the now still body of water? Does water still evaporate? ...

... Have you now stopped the entire weather cycle because rain clouds no longer form? The point I'm getting at is that there are many, many, many, many considerations to having a boundless magical effect like this. I get the feeling that you're handwaving a lot of immediate questions, which makes it hard to provide an accurate worldbuilding answer.

How are you defining "touching", at the atomic scale no actual contact usually occurs.

How much of the "thing" gets stopped? e.g. you mention touching a stream of water and the water stops, but how much of it? Just the molecules it touches? A small block of water? The entire stream? And if it's the entire stream, then what about the river it flows into, and the ocean that river flows into, etc. ? What about the rain? Do raindrops just hang in the air when they're touched?

Good worldbuilding means balancing your magic system
The son of some friends of mine once asked me to evaluate a Star Trek-based Federation space ship they'd created. As is common with 9-11 year olds, the ship was ridiculously overpowered, overarmored, and was brought into existence without even a thought toward economics (what 9-11 year old thinks about economics?). I told him it was a cool ship, but he'd get bored with it quickly. "No way!" he claimed, and off he went.
Not even a week later he and his friends were bored to death with it. The design lacked a simple reality that made it fun to play with — weaknesses. No design is perfect. Energy is not infinite. Armor acts against agility. And things cost! I explained all this to him and he spent months having fun developing space ships that could be beaten.
Godlike powers, like godlike characters, are boring
Which brings me to a basic axiom of worldbuilding: godlike things are boring. Questions asking "how do I defeat my godlike character" appear regularly on this site and they all have the same answer: you can't unless you introduce a weakness.
Let's consider your sword: as defined, your sword is instantly useless. Perhaps even before it's pulled from its scabbard, it would become surrounded by immovable air. To what extent does the effect take place? When you touch a river, does every drop of water that connects to that river also become solid (which is what "motionless" would mean)? If so, the entire atmosphere of the planet would instantly stop moving. Everything dies. Story over. We need some limitations. We need some weaknesses.
So... what's the weakness in your magic system? Here are some possibilities...
#1 Your sword will only render motionless objects with a density greater than Jell-o.
A common magical trope is that a device does what it needs to do only to those people or objects it's intentionally used against and only at the time it's required. That's pure magic! The device basically reads the user's mind. Let's introduce some persistent and consistent logic, instead. So, rule #1: the density must be greater than Jell-o or it won't be rendered motionless. This saves the atmosphere and water. It also saves the bowl of gruel you're trying to eat when your little boy decides to play with daddy's toy.
#2 Only 500kg of mass can be rendered motionless
My next problem is an effort to keep the entire planet from being rendered motionless the moment the sword is drawn. Gratefully, it's only the entire planet and not the entire universe because I can rationalize there isn't enough "stuff" between planets and solar systems to render all of reality motionless. But still, the planet, right? So your sword can only render 500kg motionless at a time. That means you can render up to something the size of a horse motionless, but not bigger. Density plays a factor. The volume of rock you can render motionless (a bit redundant, but work with me) is less than the volume of biomatter you can affect.
#3 You can only do this once a day
Third, there's a cool-down time for your sword's super power. This really is a necessity or you can have some gonzo teenager who just drank too much coffee rendering the whole honking town motionless because mom & dad won't let the teen go out with friends without first doing homework. You know I'm right. We've all been there. The bottom line is that your sword cannot have a limitless capacity to freeze things.
#4 You need to cut something, not just slap it
Remember that angry teenager? Now let's make it an angry 6-year-old who doesn't have the strength to lift the sword — but the little snot can drag it. You can find the chip-off-the-old-block easily enough by walking along the path of frozen ground, plants, the family dog, etc. because that cute little bundle of joy decided it'd be fun to pick up the hilt and run like crazy! Gratefully, the sword's designer was smart enough to not allow that. You can't just casually slap someone with the flat of the blade, you must actually strike them with the edge! Let's say the sword magically passes through the now motionless victim. Call that rule #4a.
#5 Let's redefine "motionless"
Finally, you need to remember that planets move all over the place. When you say "motionless" what you probably mean is, "that object stays where it is relative to the ground forever." But let's start with something more amusing! What happens as the planet rotates, orbits, and moves with its sun and galaxy? If "motionless" means universal motionless then the victim is instantly torn through the planet at about 720,000 km/h and just over a minute later the victim punches through the planet into open space.
Or perhaps you mean, "the victim stays relative to the center of the planet forever."  What happens if the ground is eroded in a flood? or the fight took place in a tree that later burns to the ground or falls over? Does the victim float in the air forever? Are we motionless in regard to a universal center, galactic center, solar center, planetary center or ... what?
So, your victims are in motion but let's say they're synchronized with the planet and subject to changes in the environment. If you strike an unlucky pirate that pirate will stand on the deck of the boat regardless the motion of the boat. (Now THAT's magic!) But if the boat sinks, the pirate sinks with it. If the ground erodes, the victim sinks with it. If the tree falls over, the victim falls with it. Etc.
Hopefully this got you started
Good worldbuilding is as much about weaknesses as it is strengths and about consequences as it is effects. Asking "what happens if everything something touches stops moving?" isn't useful because, taken literally, Bad Things happen... to your story. You should never try to preserve the godlike nature of anything. You should always ask yourself, "what weakness would be useful to my world or my story?"
Because there must always be at least one. (Or plan on being bored to death in a week.)
Ooooh! I just thought of something! You really want this sword during a siege because any rock the sword "strikes" is rendered instantly "motionless," but thanks to rule #5, it can be put into a catapult or trebuchet! That means you have an unbreakable munition striking a breakable wall. Sucks to be you, Caesar!

I wish all answers were like this.

I would think that the catapult rock would move with the catapult arm (or trebuchet sling)... but fail to detach from it, as it is motionless relative to the catapult (arm) / trebuchet (sling). Flying through the air, especially at a ballistic arc, would not be supported by rule #5 as I understand it after my quick reading of your answer? Which is amazing otherwise, btw.

Just a little remark: A six year old would defintely be able to lift a sword and even swing it (albeit not very graciously). Keeping in mind that your average swords weighs between 1 and 2 Kilograms I would be very concerned for every 6 year old who cant lift it and do an atleast clumsy swing.

All good points, but I think #3 could be relaxed to several times a day or even dropped and it still be a good balanced magical weapon.  The Ice Queen's wand in the Chronicles of Narnia would seem a lot less menacing if she could only freeze one good guy per day.

On a side note, I love that your friend let the son play with the OP ship and decide for himself that it was a problem.  That said, it could have been a different sort of learning experience.  While most DMs leave it to the players to outsmart superior but "dumb" BBEGs, it can also be a fun experience to let the players have their OP stuff and force them to face complex asymmetric and/or political warfare tactics.  A dungeon full of Kobolds or a low level civil employee can still present real challenges a high level party if you make them clever enough.

@EisGeflüster That depends on the sword. When a teenager, a friend of mine commissioned a local blacksmith to make him a sword. A bastard sword. At 16 I could barely lift the sword by its hilt with two hands. It weighed much more than 2kg. But I hope you're not missing my point - that was merely a story to demonstrate a problem. I couldn't care less if it was or wasn't realistic.

A bastard sword aka Longsword aka hand-and-a-half sword weighs about 2 kg. I use one regularly. It is designed so an adult can wield it with one hand if necessary, albeit you usually use both hands to wield it. Maybe you're thinking of a Zweihänder/Montante/Bidenhänder, which can weigh up to 6kg and are longer than a grown man is tall. I'd still be very concerned for any 16 year old who can't lift it. Maybe the blacksmith made it out of lead?
Yes, I get your point and it still stands of course. I'm just a sword enthusiast who wants to debunk some sword myths.

@EisGeflüster Are we arguing? The blacksmith made my friend a sword. My friend called it a bastard sword. It weighed a lot more than 2kg. Your opinion means absolutely nothing to me considering my personal experience. Insofar as I'm concerned, you're an overzealous sword enthusiast who has never commissioned a blacksmith to actually make a sword from scratch without modern manufacturing methods and materials. I'm certainly impressed by what the old blacksmiths could do including how light their swords could be - but what you find in museums is only a single snapshot of reality.

If we stay true to your definitions I am afraid your sword can never be used.
Since everything it touches would stop moving, it would create a layer of perfectly still air (or whatever medium is around it) all around its blade, which would make wielding or swinging the blade impossible. Even worse, considering that Earth rotate on itself, around the Sun, around the center of the galaxy and so on and so forth, the now motionless sword would be flung in some general direction at a velocity of few hundreds km/s, carrying with it its surprised wielder.

Even if the air doesn't count as a "substance", specs of dust (human skin, silica etc..) are everywhere and way more common than the human eye normally sees.

Everyone would die
Let's think this through. For the person wielding the sword to think it was stopped, it would probably have to be stopped relative to the person, or at least relative to the sword. If something stayed stopped relative to the sword, then when you pulled the sword away, you would also have to pull the stopped item with it. Either it would add its weight to the sword, or it would be massless, and you could wind up waving an entire river around.
So, for the purpose of "makes any kind of sense," let's say it is stopped relative to the sword's wielder. The immediate effect would be that the object would follow the wielder around, but you can apply a secondary power that disconnects the sword, allowing the frozen mass to revert to normal gravity and momentum effects. This means you might be able to break the sword by swinging it into something that instantaneously becomes an immovable object.
You specify that it might affect a stream, so we can assume that a "thing" is defined by contact and similarity of state of matter. Honesty, that's more than a little vague, but let's roll with it. This brings up all sorts of issues when we're talking about contacting a person, because a human body is a bunch of microscopic solid bags of fluid with layers of colloidal suspension between them. A deep cut could freeze their circulatory system, but a graze might just freeze a patch of skin.
Air is more problematic. It's kept out of any particular area because there is already air in that area pushing back. If the air that touches the sword stops, it is no longer pushing back. The effect would be a huge sucking vacuum, as if someone had opened a hole into outer space.
The air would build up a layer around it that would quickly expand to touch/encompass everything near it. Now you have two options.

decide that second-hand touches count, and eventually everyone dies.
decide that second-hand touches don't count, in which case you have to ask if air-to-air counts as second-hand.
a. If it does, then the atmosphere builds up around it, encasing the country side around it and suffocating the rest of the planet. Everyone dies.
b. If it doesn't then you have a sword that's encased in stopped air and can't touch anything else.

2b gives you an interesting possibility. In order to touch something, you have to wipe away a layer of air. This wouldn't happen if you smacked someone with the side of the blade, but would if you put the sword into them. It would probably work if you sliced them, but it's your magic.
Fields aren't actual things you can touch. They are forces that act upon objects. If it can freeze fields, everybody dies. No exceptions.
Waves are a motion that particles perform, not actual entities.
You never specified if the touched object could ever be unfrozen. If not, then your sword could very easily become trapped.

Strongbad: Your WORLD A-Splode.

"Fun" effect, an object with zero velocity, and thus no momentum, cannot occupy a definite physical location, see Heisenberg. This means that everything the sword touches, for all intents and purposes, ceases to exist, at least it can no longer be interacted with in any meaningful way because you can't find it anymore.
That assumes some universally acceptable frame of reference against which the motion of the object in question can be measured, this does not exist, so the reality is probably worse: if the sword freezes the object with reference to any physical point, that point is itself in motion with reference to all other objects in the universe. [subatomic] Particles that interact with the sword are going to shoot off in strange directions with reference to the wielder, punching through everything in their way in the process.

The Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle applies to quantum particles, not objects on a macro scale.

@WillRoss1 Yes and the sword would be plucking subatomic particles out of the matter it interacted with individually as it "touched" them.

Motion Smotion
A lot of answers have brought up the problem of relativistic motion, which is fair, but it is also a MAJOR problem with time travel and teleportation and we hand wave that away all the time. So I want to go a different direction and focus not on the word "movement", but instead on the word "everything".

What comprises a "thing" is contextual
My body can be considered a thing, but it is comprised of individual parts that are also things. If your sword hits my arm, is my arm the thing that was hit, or am I? A river is a thing, so stabbing it would stop the river, but a bend or a fork in the river are also things, so if you hit it there does the entire river stop or just the bend/fork? If you poke a castle wall, is the entire castle impenetrable? Just that side? Just the individual stone? I'm sure you get my point.
Defining a "thing"
So, what we need is a consistent definition for what exactly a "thing" is in terms of the sword. If you hit a boulder, you aren't actually hitting all of the boulder, just a thin slice of it. So here's my suggestion: the "things" your sword is touching are not entire objects as we would see them, but the atoms/molecules that make up the objects.

How does this work?
The blade of the sword is essentially ethereal: it passes through objects as though they weren't there. But as it passes through the object, any atoms in it's way (or within a small distance of it) are rendered motionless. For most solid objects this is roughly the same as rendering the entire object motionless, since all the atoms are tightly bound to the ones that are "frozen". Non solid objects get a bit more interesting.
Example #1: Boulder
Slice it through a boulder and the entire boulder stops moving, but the sections not directly affected by the sword can still break off or erode away. If a more solid anchor is needed, or erosion needs to be minimized, it's simply a matter of slicing through it multiple times at different angles.
Example #2: River
This solves the issues with rivers while maintaining some interesting utility: slicing through the water creates a thin, but impenetrable barrier of solid water. You can't "freeze" an entire river, but you could dam one up or reroute the flow with relatively little effort.
Example #3: Castle
Slicing through a castle wall will not make the castle impenetrable, but may reinforce a small section. Taking a couple days to systematically make a lot of slices in a structurally sound pattern could potentially make it significantly harder to get through.
Example #4: People
And as for people, well, that's where it might start to get a little gruesome, so you might have to be careful, depending on your target audience. If you hit someone in the aforementioned arm, the whole arm doesn't "freeze" nor does the entire body, but rather a thin cross section of skin, muscle, blood and bone. I won't go into any gory details here, but it's no longer a matter of "oh, you hit them, they are a solid statue now", it's a bit messier than that (I'd be happy to explain in a DM).

What about air?
As mentioned in other answers, how the blade affects the air is a big concern. If it is ethereal, as I mentioned previously, it doesn't run the risk of getting stuck in a pocket of solid air, but it would leave a permanent, invisible trail of solid air everywhere it went, which could get really complicated really fast.
Air solution 1
To address this you could make the sword inactive (a regular sword) until the user intentionally uses it's special ability (leaving room to intentionally create walls of air). This is fine, but not very interesting.
Air solution 2
To make it more interesting: it only works if the particles are close enough together to affix to one another. The atoms in liquids and solids already have a weak or strong bond, respectively, with each other, which the sword manipulates to produce the effect; gases, on the other hand have atoms that are not attracted to each other, preventing the sword from working properly.

Balance
As mentioned in the other answers, this sword is crazy OP, but that doesn't mean it can't work. Using my suggestions above will take it down a few notches, from "accidentally destroy the planet" to "easily destroy anything and everything you want", which is a step in the right direction, but still isn't likely to make for a very compelling story. Let's take a look at some ways that it might work.
NOT the protagonists weapon!
I cannot stress this enough. This sword is WAY too powerful to be in the hands of the protagonist, as it renders any challenge trivial, which isn't very exciting.
Unless...
...you significantly nerf it or introduce MAJOR restrictions or drawbacks. Perhaps, in order to use it, you have to find a way to become ethereal yourself, which is very difficult, risky and taxing. Or maybe it becomes less ethereal as it is used, making it harder and harder to cut through things until it has had sufficient time to recharge.
It's the antagonists weapon
This is much more interesting, as it makes the ridiculously overpowered weapon an obstacle to overcome instead of the answer to everything. It also allows you to introduce strange occurrences, like finding immovable boulders, sheets of solid water or a decayed hand suspended in the air. Then, later, you reveal where all these things are coming from and the protagonist (and reader) finds out they have been learning how the sword works the entire time without realizing it. One thing to keep in mind is what to do with the sword when the antagonist is inevitably defeated. You'll need a good reason for the antagonist not to take it, or you can say goodbye to a sequel! Maybe it's cursed and turns you evil or something, there are plenty of options.
It's a lost ancient relic
Probably not where you want to go with this, but it's worth mentioning. The sword could be an ancient relic that has been lost to time, but left behind the things that it permanently "froze". This allows you to use it as a plot device that shapes certain environments, without it getting in the way of the story.

I like that last suggestion +1

Stops moving relative to what ?
You tagged "science-based", so:

Earth rotates. Speed at the equator is about 50 cm/sec. But that barely matters, because:
The Earth moves around the sun at about 30 km/sec.
The solar system is moving around the center of the galaxy at about 230 km/sec.

So from a science POV, if you stop movement in any somewhat absolute sense, there'd be a supersonic boom and whatever you touched has disappeared, or is smeared over the nearest hard surface.
From a purely science-based view, stopping movement is impossible. It would violate Newton's laws. If I push the object, it must move. If it's very heavy it would move imperceptibly, but you excerpt gravitational pull on the Earth just as much as it does on you. It's just that the effect is less than an atom's width and is balanced out by other people around the globe.
